# Errors on deploying an Azure Document DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azureportal

I'm having problems while deploying a new Document DB for my project.

All the validations appear to be correct, at least they all have a green mark.

Once I click on "Create" button, the page does like an immediate refresh, and the create button turns grey (disabled) and nothing happens.

Other deployments works as expected (web apps, vms etc)

Also one of my colleges tried without any luck either.

I've tried with multiple browsers, clear cookies and browse history, also tried in incognito mode.

[image: image of error]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you're seeing on the portal?

Comment: @GauravMantri here's the same image I shared with AzureSupport on twitter: [Images Here](http://imgur.com/a/QTy9U), from the step 3->4 happens like an immediate refresh, and nothing happens.

Comment: We are investigating.

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues - in the future, please edit your question when you have more details. I embedded the image into your question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon thank you, I didn't know I could do that in the question body. I'll follow your advise in future questions.

Answer (score 2):

Bruno, We've rolled out a change to the portal and this should be fixed. Can you retry?

Comment: Thank you @MimiGentz, it worked! See image below, there were some missing fields in my first attempts.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSHtx.png)